# Fetching phone number with country code from Google people API

Tags: google-api, phone-number

We are integrating social signup with google in our project, so we have to get the phone number from the users google account. we were able to fetch the phone number from people API(by using phoneNumber scope), but its not returning any country code info. please help us to get the country or country code info along with phone number.

The scope we used is: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read

and we used this API to fetch phoneNumbers:
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers

we got the response as

```
{
    "resourceName": "people/11454441970xxxxxx",
    "etag": "%EgUBCy43PxoEAQIFByIMaXF6QTFjxxxx",
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "primary": true,
                "source": {
                    "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
                    "id": "11454441970xxxxxx"
                }
            },
            "value": "95xxxxxxxx",
            "type": "work",
            "formattedType": "Work"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The field you are looking for is called canonicalForm which is the  The canonicalized [ITU-T E.164](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/004/itu-t.E.164.1.2008.pdf) form of the phone number.

The people api is very picky with what information the user has summited. If the user you are looking at did not add the country code then its not going to appear

As you can see with my settings on my [google profile](https://myaccount.google.com/profile/phone/edit?index=0) I have set my country code with my phone number

[image].

So when i make a request to the api.

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

My phone number is returned in the id field and country code and number in the canonicalForm  fields.

```
 "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "3fab08baa4be"
        }
      },
      "value": "xxxxxxxxx",
      "canonicalForm": "+45xxxxxxxxx",
      "type": "mobile",
      "formattedType": "Mobile"
    },
```

I would check the data that the user has inserted into their google profile and ensure that they have set the country code.